# node.js hangs when connecting to mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been having trouble connecting to my local MongoDB, so I figured trying to connect to an atlas database. Still have no luck. I think the issue is with my windows install at this point.

I can connect using MongoDB Compass no problem, using the same uri.

No errors are thrown. Just hangs.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:password@main.9nwa88e.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to database!');

  // Perform database operations here...

  db.close(); 
});
```

Check my previous posts if you want an idea of what I've been dealing with.

I tried disabling my firewall and windows defender.
I made sure not to have < > around the username and password.
I also tried mongoose.

Comment: What version of mongodb node module are you using? The newer version do not call the callback in connect anymore and use promises instead. Read the docs.

Comment: @Marc Adjusting my code to expect a promise rather than a callback fixed everything, thank you so much. if you post the answer I will give it an upvote and check mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, newer mongodb packages from npm do not exepect/call the provided callback anymore.

`MongoClient.connect(...)` instead returns a promise.

This is a breaking change.